# fixing overlap graphics in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using the subplot method to make my work more orderly but I don't know how to fix the overlap of the graphics. Here is my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('churn.csv')
fugados=data[data.Churn=='Yes']
noFugados=data[data.Churn=='No']

plt.subplot(3,2,1)
plt.title('Cantidad de clientes y fugados [1]')
plt.scatter('Fugados',fugados.Churn.size)
plt.scatter('Clientes',noFugados.Churn.size)
plt.ylabel('Cantidad de personas')

plt.subplot(3,2,2)
plt.title('Cantidad de hombres y mujeres [2]')
m=data[data.gender=='Female']
h=data[data.gender=='Male']
plt.scatter('Hombres',h.gender.size)
plt.scatter('Mujeres',m.gender.size)
plt.ylabel('Cantidad de personas')

plt.subplot(3,2,3)
plt.title('Cantidad de hombres y mujeres fugados [3]')
m=data[(data.gender=='Female') & (data.Churn=='Yes')]
h=data[(data.gender=='Male') & (data.Churn=='Yes')]
plt.scatter('Hombres',h.gender.size)
plt.scatter('Mujeres',m.gender.size)
plt.ylabel('Cantidad de personas')

plt.subplot(3,2,4)
plt.title('Cantidad de hombres y mujeres que son clientes [4]')
m=data[(data.gender=='Female') & (data.Churn=='No')]
h=data[(data.gender=='Male') & (data.Churn=='No')]
plt.scatter('Hombres',h.gender.size)
plt.scatter('Mujeres',m.gender.size)
plt.ylabel('Cantidad de personas')
plt.subplot(3,2,5)
plt.title('Cantidad de fugados que tenían fibra óptica u otro servicio [5]')
conFibra=data[(data.InternetService=='Fiber optic') & (data.Churn=='Yes')]
sinFibra=data[(data.InternetService!='Fiber optic') & (data.Churn=='Yes')]
plt.scatter('Fibra óptica',conFibra.gender.size)
plt.scatter('Otro servicio',sinFibra.gender.size)
plt.ylabel('Cantidad de personas')
```

This is the output :
[image: plot]

If someone can help me to show something more clear and organized I would appreciate that. I want to separate the graphics.

Comment: Here I see three things to optimize (1) Make the figure larger (2) Use linebreaks in long titles, (3) change the margins and spacings between subplots (`plt.tight_layout` or `plt.subplots_adjust`)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the `plt.tight_layout()` before show?

Ref: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html